# QtCreator with CLang in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, clang, qt-creator

Im coding with QtCreator on Ubuntu 14. I have installed Clang 3.5 and LLVM framework 3.5.

1. How can I configure QtCreator to load the native LLVM libraries that enable me to work with it's structure (like PassManager class, Stringref class, and so on)?
2. How can I configure QtCreator to compile my X.cpp modules to LLVM shared object files (.so)?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have now updated to clang 3.7 and LLVM 3.7. I have enabled qt KIT to compile with clang instead of GCC, and it works, but no .so files are generated, also, when i try to access LLVM class hierarchy, no code completion is displayed.